# Какой ssh сервер лучше всего использовать под Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: ssh, windows-server

Необходимо установить ssh на win-сервер. Какой лучше всего выбрать? 
Нашел много различных вариантов, в которых можно запросто потеряться. Необходим бесплатный и хороший функционал, пусть и долго в нем разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

[WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) (Personal Edition - бесплатно для некоммерческого использования) - достаточно неплохой из тех, что мне известны:

- поддерживает PowerShell;
- есть API для автоматизации;
- пишет логи;
- настраивается по пользователю, группе, IP, DNS;
- поддерживает публичные ключи OpenSSH;
- и разные другие вещи, смотрите ссылку.